# Top 30 informal phone offer, what are the chance of not receiving the formal offer?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

Say I receive a phone call from a US school among top 30 in my field, offering me a PhD position, stating that the formal proposal should arrive in a week or so.

Am I wrong in assuming that the chance of the letter never arriving are zero almost surely?

Comment: Never assume. However, this sounds generally good. That being said, being accepted to a PhD is something that does happen, so I wouldn't know why it would be unlikely, as your question seems to implicitly assume.

Comment: You will know in a week or so.

Comment: The question isn't clear to me.  What action are you going to take based on this probability?  I wouldn't retract your other applications yet, since there is nothing to be gained by doing that.  Are you just asking in order to calm your nerves?

Comment: In my opinion, the question is clear. But, the purpose of the question is unclear. I voted to Leave Open.

Comment: I am guessing it is not for a PhD in statistics :)

Comment: @DavidKetcheson question seems very clear to me. Why the OP wants the info seems irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: @scaaahu despite your comment, it looks like you voted to close the question.

Comment: If you are a frequentist: yes, you are wrong. If you are a Bayesian: there are no wrong assumptions, the question is how you will modify your priors at the end of next week.

Comment: This is almost certainly part of their formal admission process. While administration prepares a written (paper/email) offer based on standard forms (possibly adjusted to your situation as advised by the program director), someone is often designated to call people to show the program's interest in you - if *they* want you, it's assumed others do too. It's extremely unlikely a written offer won't follow if the phone call didn't go catastrophically, but wait patiently for the letter to arrive.

Comment: I think if you just want to calm your nerves, I can say it would be highly unusual for someone to offer you admittance over the phone but then change their mind later. It is not strictly a 0% chance, as what you were told over the phone is not especially binding on the department and University as a whole (almost everyone has a boss that generally has veto power over what you want). From this you can conclude you shouldn't flip-off everyone around you, email other programs telling them to stuff it, and scream "I'm outta here, suckers!" You probably shouldn't do that after the paperwork, either